# I need to size down and move my list, but the margin is totally ignored

Tags: html, css, margin

HTML:

```
<list id="main-list">
        <ul>obsah0</ul>
        <ul>obsah1</ul>
        <ul>obsah2</ul>
        <ul>obsah3</ul>
        <ul>obsah4</ul>
        <ul>obsah5</ul>
</list>
```

CSS:

```
#main-list {
    width: 80vw;
    margin-left: 200px;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: darkblue;
}
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEZyg.png)

I tried everything, but the list is still ignoring my margin-left. Don't have slightest what am I doing wrong. :( Please help.

Comment: Hi @Jarin could you please tell me where exactly you want to position your list? at the far left(start) of the screen, center or far right(end) of screen. It's a little hard to help you when I don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but if you want it centered and to scale responisvely try setting you margin to auto

````
```#main-list {
width: 80vw;
margin: 0 auto;

display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-around;
flex-wrap: wrap;

border-bottom-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
border-color: darkblue;
````

}```

Comment: Yep, I want it centered and to scale responisvely. But this solution doesn't work for me. The list is still stick to the left side as on the picture.

Comment: I thought, that something from outside the element can affect it, but the #main-list element is only inside the body element; Where is nothing...